# Use dplyr to change all values above threshold to NA

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, pipe

I have a data frame of numbers and I want to change all values over 8 to NA. I know there are other ways to do this, but I would like to accomplish this using dplyr so I can use a pipe with other code I have.

```
df <- data.frame(c(1:9), c(2:10))
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), function(x) ifelse(x>8, NA, x)))

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), function(x) na_if(x >8)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assign the output to the original object to make those changes as the `%>%` will not do the output printed on the console.

```
df <- df %>% 
       mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(. > 8, NA, .)))
```

---

Or another option is `%<>%` operator from `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(. > 8, NA, .)))
```